# UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is not raised while keyboard is split (iPad)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, keyboard

As in iPad, when we press return value on textfield then `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` is raised. But when we split  the the keyboard then it is not raised. Any idea ?
Thanks,

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Comment: There is no code for split keyboard. Its functionality of iOS5 and above.

Comment: I meant the code you wrote to get the notification. i.e. `addNotification` or something like that.

Comment: I found one notification method KeyboardWillChangeFrame, which occuring when we return from slip keyboard.

Comment: @Lindon :   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(KeyboardWillChangeFrame:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];

Comment: what the mean by split the the keyboard?

Comment: @Nrml, I thought that it might be something missing in your code. You can edit your question to provide more details if you want. If you post your code someone might be able to spot what is wrong (or rule that out).

Comment: @Lindon, thanks for your favorable response, i get the solution. if we puts  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(nameOfMethodYouWantToCall:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];, then it will call the method when you resign keyboard.

Comment: @Nrml, I advise you to put the code that is not working in your question, so people can see what you are doing. (click the edit link)